# Issue with deleting a list item

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

issue:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("a");
        list.Add("b");
        list.Add("c");

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item == "a")
            {
                list.Add("af");
            }
        }
```

Above is my code when i am trying to add item to list it is giving exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute". Can anybody help on this why i am getting this exception.

Comment: show your code of event and aspx pages it is not enough information

Comment: Which event fire's in your masterpage? which issues are you getting?

Comment: Cant figure out your issue with this little information. Please post your cs and aspx code

Comment: I can not post my code as this is my company security policy

Comment: You don't need to post the exact code. Make a simplified example that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise it's pretty much impossible to guess what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the list while you are iterationg over it.
But you can create another list and work on it:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("a");
list.Add("b");
list.Add("c");
List<string> tmpList = new List<string>(list);
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item == "a")
    {
        tmpList.Add("af");
    }
}
list = tmpList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the iterated collection from inside a foreach loop. This is what the error message is telling you. Since you're working with a list, you can just use a `for` loop instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] == "a")
    {
        list.Add("af");
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) that explains what you're seeing:

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to MoveNext or Reset throws an InvalidOperationException.